# Join image collections into one collection with 2 bands. Too many combinations obtained

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have two image collections (ndvi and spei) with 20 features each (one image per year). I want to combine them into one image collection with one image per year with two bands (ndvi and spei).
To do so, I tried to apply an inner Join based on the system property 'year' that I defined for each image collection.
As a result, I obtain an image collection with 400 features instead of 20, and I am not able to see where the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
var ndvi= medianCompResiduals.select('ndvi');
var spei= spei3m.map(function(img){
  return img.rename('spei')
}); 

// Add year as a system property to match with SPEI
var ndvi=ndvi.map(function(img){
  var date= ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'))
  return img.set('year', ee.Number(date.get('year')))
})
print (ndvi, 'ndvi')

var spei=spei.map(function(img){
  var date= ee.String(img.get('system:index')).slice(1,5)
  return img.set('year', ee.Number(date))
})
print (spei, 'spei')

// Use an equals filter to specify how the collections match.

var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:year',
  rightField: 'system:year'
});

// Define the join.
var innerJoin = ee.Join.inner('primary', 'secondary');

// Applt join
var collectionJoin = ee.ImageCollection(innerJoin.apply(ndvi, spei, filter )); 

// Flatten joined images into a single image with 2 bands
var Combined = collectionJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
});


// Print the result.
print('Inner join:', Combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a small enough problem that I'd just convert to lists and zip them together (as long as they're both the same length and order).  Something like:

```
merged = collection1.toList(100).zip(collection2.toList(100))
    .map(function(row) {
        return ee.Image(ee.List(row).get(0))
              .addBands(ee.List(row).get(1))
})
```